# MS-access INSERT INTO variables

Tags: ms-access

I have to make an audit trail that can keep track of the fields after `INSERT INTO`, however, I can't get any of the variables the expressions in "values" represents to go into the fields, only the expressions in `VALUES`. For instance, the two entries with numeric values give me numeric values, the others give me a string that is for instance `Form.RecordSource = clientName`

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblAudit ([RecordID], [AuditWho], [AuditWhen], [AuditWhat],     [AuditFrom], [AuditTo]) VALUES ('1', '2', 'Now()', 'Form.RecordSource = clientName' , ' Me.ClientName.Value ', '  Me.clientNameTextBox.Value  ')"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a minimum you need to do something like this:

```
Dim SQL as string

SQL = "INSERT INTO tblAudit ([RecordID], [AuditWho], [AuditWhen], [AuditWhat],     [AuditFrom], [AuditTo]) VALUES ('1', '2','" & Now() & "', 'ClientName' , '" & Me.ClientName.Value & "', '" & Me.clientNameTextBox.Value & "')"

db.Execute SQL
```

To be more "robust" you should declare variables for `AuditFrom` and `AuditTo` values and validate that the data entered is "ok" before trying to perform the insert:

```
Dim SQL as string
dim strAuditFrom as string
Dim strAuditTo As String

strAuditFrom = Me.ClientName.Value & ""
strAuditTo = Me.ClientNameTextBox.Value & ""

if strAuditTo = vbNullString then
  'Alert the user or throw an error perhaps?
end if

sql = "INSERT INTO tblAudit ([RecordID], [AuditWho], [AuditWhen], [AuditWhat],   [AuditFrom], [AuditTo]) VALUES ('1', '2','" & Now() & "', 'ClientName' , '" &strAuditFrom & "', '" & strAuditTo & "')"

db.Execute sql
```

Comment: Tim, you forgot to escape the string for the Now() function.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the text to insert by using the single qoutes. To get a value from a control and have it included in your query you need to escape the string using a double qoute, concatacate the string with the ampersand, find the value of the control, and continue the string with the ampsand and double qoute. For example:

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblOne (Field1, Field2) VALUES ('literal text','" & ctlSomething & "')"
```